# next.js CSS not load after router.push

Tags: css, next.js, next.js14

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import { getToken } from '@api/auth/auth';
import { ROUTES } from '@constants/routes';

const Bridge = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const { authType, code } = router.query as any;
    const a = async () => {
       if (!authType || !code) return;
       const data = await getToken(authType, code);
       localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
       Cookies.set('refreshToken', data.refreshToken);

       router.push(ROUTES.WRITE);
    };
    a();
  }, [router.query, router]);

  return null;
};

export default Bridge;
```

This is my code.
This page's function is to set the token and navigate to the WRITE page. But when navigate to WRITE page, CSS not load. I don't know why CSS file doesn't load in WRITE page. I'm using next.js 14 page router and vanilla extract css.

Comment: maybe ```router.reload()```  can reload